# Problem with the definition of $\eta$-*long normal forms*

Tags: type-theory

I'm studying type theory and I have just started with it. In order to introduce myself in this field I'm studying the book "Lectures on the Curry-Howard isomorphism" by Morten Heine Sørensen and Pawel Urzyczyn.

In chapter 4 of this book it is defined (definition 4.2.1.) the notion of $\eta$-*long normal form* (or simply *long normal form*).

The definition is given recursively as follows:

- If $x$ is a variable of type $\tau_1\rightarrow\cdots\rightarrow\tau_n\rightarrow p$, and $M_1^{\tau_1},\dots, M_n^{\tau_n}$ are in $\eta$-long normal form, then $(xM_1\dots M_n)^{p}$ is in $\eta$-long normal form.
- If $M^\sigma$ is in $\eta$-long normal form then so is $(\lambda x:\tau.M)^{\tau\rightarrow\sigma}$.

Also, terms of shape $\lambda x_1^{\tau_1}\dots x_n^{\tau_n}. y\vec{N}$ where $\vec{N}$ are normal form are given as an equivalent definition.

Before introducing this definition, the authors explain that is a restriction of the notion of *normal form* which has been previously introduced.

I'm having some problems with the definition.

First, I think I do not understand the first definition that is given. In particular, I see how can I construct from terms which already are in long normal form another long normal forms, but I don't see and "atomic" case of normal form (I'm sorry if this explanation of the problem is very poor, I'm going to try to explain it in other ways to make it clear). We have that $x$ is a variable and we add terms $M_i^{\tau_i}$ to construct another long normal form, but what is the shape $M_i^{\tau_i}$? It is not clarify in the second point, are variables (in particular is variable $x$) in $\eta$-long normal form or this is what the definition wants to avoid?

Second, I don't understand what is the difference between terms of the form $\lambda x_1^{\tau_1}\dots x_n^{\tau_n}. y\vec{N}$ where $\vec{N}$ are normal forms and the compact expression for normal form mentioned in remark 1.3.7 of this book (remark which is applied in proposition 4.1.2. in this chapter).

Finally, I do not understand why these two definitions are equivalent, I would see the equivalence if in the first point of the first definition (If $x$ is a variable of type...) the $M_i^{\tau_i}$ where in long normal form or the $\vec{N}$ in the second definition where in $\eta$-long normal form. But as is written in the book I don't see this equivalence.

As summary, I would like to understand what is exactly the restriction we are doing with this definition and (if it is not very hard to explain) why is this restriction desirable (what are the consequences of this restriction).

I apologize for my bad English, is not my native language and (even if I can read it) I have some problems with the writing. Thank you for reading.

Comment: If you are quoting from a text you should use a blockquote. If you are paraphrasing, you don't need a blockquote but in this case I would recommend including exact quotes as well as the details matter. Similarly, referring to definitions and propositions without providing them isn't helpful to people who don't have access to the text. There is also context that is important. I'm very confident $p$ stands for an *atomic* type (which is why $p$ is used and not $\tau$) which is important but is not evident from what you provided. You should try to make questions as self-contained as practicable.

Comment: "why is this restriction desirable" I would say it is mostly a matter of convenience.  if you have beta normal form, then
(\ f : Nat -> Nat. \ x : Nat. f x )  : (Nat -> Nat) -> Nat -> Nat
is distinct from
(\ f : Nat -> Nat.  f )  : (Nat -> Nat) -> Nat -> Nat
even though they have the same type and do the same thing.  but (\ f : Nat -> Nat.  f ) is not in eta long form, expanding it makes the functions equal.